# HTML table issue (fixed left cell, right cell filling all rest of the content)

Tags: html

I need a help with a table that I can't get right. It is a very simple table with only two cells (left and right):

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td width="100px">
       my content 1
     </td>
     <td>
       my content2
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want the one on the left to be of a fixed size (100px) and the right one to expand until the rest of the page.

The issue is that none of what I tried worked. If I leave as is, it will just be as big as "my content 2".

I tried to put a hidden element (like an image) on the second  to make sure it goes all the way, but on my small netbook, it goes above the size of the table and breaks it. So I can't define a image to be as large as the screen.

Any other ideas? It should be simple, but I can't get it done.

Comment: Do you want the `width` of 2nd column to be fixed to fit rest of the page? or you want to dynamically increase the width of 2nd column upon adding contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width: 100%` to your table

http://jsfiddle.net/rU9Tu/

Answer (score 0):

Typically, table resizes to its content, so you need set table to take the full length available.

```
<table width="100%">
...
</table>
```